# Declare factory with generic types from own class

Tags: typescript, generics, factory

I try to declare (interface only) factory which provides any generic types from own class to result.

At first, I declare any classes. `Foo` is base class. `Moo` is some user class.

```js
declare module 'any-module' {
    class Foo<T> {
        get test(): T;
    }

    class Moo<T> extends Foo<T> {
         get moo(): T;
    }
}
```

Then, I try to declare factory which know about `Foo` but do not know about `Moo`. This factory must be produce `Foo`-like classes by instance from extends of `Foo` (`Moo` for example).

```js
interface IFactory<T> {
    create(Instance) => ??? /* like: new Instance<T>() */
}
```

So, I tryed any ways for that:

```js
interface IFactory<T> {
    create1<R extends Foo<T>>(instance: new (...ars: any) => R): R;
    create2<X extends new (...ars: any) => Foo<T>>(instance: X): InstanceType<X>;
}
```

but no of above ways does not work correctly

```js
// Getting factory with string generic
const factory = {} as IFactory<string>;
    
factory.create1(Moo) // Generic type is string, but result is Foo 
factory.create2(Moo) // Result is Moo, but generic type is unknown
```

Thanks!

Comment: `get test(): T;` this is ivalid syntax. You are trying to define `moo` getter for non existance property. Please fix your example

Comment: Hi! It is not actualy mistake. It is an TS declaration for existing module. I made some correction in example. Thanks for note.

Comment: It will work if you explicitly specify the generic type: `factory.create1<Moo<string>>(Moo);`, or specify the type of the variable: `var moo: Moo<string> = factory.create(Moo);`.

Comment: Yes, it is. But main problem is inconsistency of one. For example, if i make factory with string type, i will make mistake when will call `create` with another type, like `create<number>()`, So, it is important able to calling the factory without generic types